# Qt: Generate ui_ classes using uic, load dynamically by class name

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to load an .ui class generated by uic, dynamically by class name? I need to decide which UI class to load dynamically. I do not have that information at compile time. I do not want to use QUiLoader. Instead, I want to combine the [direct approach here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-direct-approach) with QMetaType object instantiation by string.

I.e.

1. add the UI file to FORMS in project file,
2. declare the UI classes for QMetaType usage Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Ui::planar_break) or Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Ui_planar_break)
3. then form a string class name dynamically depending on user action: "Ui::planar_break" or "Ui_planar_break"
4. and invoke the below function to get the UI widget pointer for usage?

> ```
> QWidget* initiateClassByName(QString name){
>     int id = QMetaType::type(name.toLatin1());
>     QWidget* widget=nullptr;
>     if (id != QMetaType::UnknownType) {
>         widget=static_cast< QWidget* > (QMetaType::create(id));
>         //QMetaType::destroy(id, myClassPtr);
>         //myClassPtr = 0;
>     }
>     return widget;
> }
> ```

I am trying to increase the performance, compared to loading a dozen or so UI files (stored in Qt resource files) dynamically every time a specific dialog is instantiated. When I do this I seem to get a QMetaType::UnknownType every time. Ideas? Thanks.

(Hm, not sure why my function wasn't showing as code block here, until I made it a quotation.)

Answer (score 1):

uic creates C++ code. If you really want to dynamically create a widget/dialog out of an xml file at runtime, you need to use the [Qt Ui Tools](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtuitools-module.html). The class [QUiLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html) might be what you are looking for. If you do this, you can query the created QWidget through QWidget::findChild You can interact with the UI items through [QObject::findChild()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild), provided you give your widgets distinct and meaningful object names.

Comment: This is what I am doing now, and trying to avoid. I want to get to a more performant solution by getting the UI files precompiled and then only choosing runtime which UI class to instantiate.

Comment: Ok, got it. In that case, reading the API documentation of [QUiLoader::creaetWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html#createWidget) sounds interesting. I personally didn't entirely get though, how these widget names are registered. Does it only work over some Qt plugin mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, based on discussion had in #qt irc channel on Freenode I think what I am asking is actually not feasible.

My understanding is that even if I could get the C++ headers compiled and the classes registered using perhaps also qRegisterMetaType(), and perhaps even get them instantiated using QMetaType, to actually get the UI built I would have to call setupUi() on the instance.

Since UI files do not implement a common interface that includes setupUi, and I don't know compile-time which class I am instantiating, calling setupUi becomes impossible.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you still could try to implement your own system of a widget factory, where you can register widget provides. Each widget provider has a list of classes it can instantiate. the widget factory would then query all its widget providers for the supported class names, and on a match, passes the createWidget call on to the matching widget provider. That would work, but not at compile-time. You'd still need to maintain this list (i.e. register widget providers) at runtime.